# How to fix that procedure in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created procedure which count not null rows in the column, but query throws errors: @tableName is not declared and invalid object name tempTable. I don't know why code throws that errors, because all variables are declared.

```
Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getLenCol, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 0]
Must declare the table variable "@tableName".
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid object name 'tempTable'.


CREATE OR ALTER PROC getLenCol
      @tableName  varchar(255),
      @colName varchar(255)
    as
      DECLARE @tempTable Table(smth varchar(255));
      DECLARE @query varchar(255)
      insert into @tempTable(smth) select @colName from @tableName where @colName is not null
      exec (@query)
      select @@ROWCOUNT
    GO
    exec getLenCol 'users','name'
```

Also when I make that program in another way, that code throw
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 11
error.

```
Must declare the table variable "@tempTable".

CREATE OR ALTER PROC getLenCol
  @tableName  varchar(255),
  @colName varchar(255)
as
  DECLARE @tempTable Table(smth varchar(255))
  DECLARE @query varchar(255)
  SET @query = concat('insert into @tempTable(smth) select ',@colName,' from ',@tableName,' where ',@colName,' is not null');/*@colName from @tableName where @colName is not NULL*/
  exec (@query)
  select @@ROWCOUNT
GO
exec getLenCol 'users','name'
```

Is it a way to fix that error?

Comment: Variables only exist in the scope that they were declared in, also the above is *wide* open to injection attack.s Why do you need to write a dynamic approach for this at all? What's wrong with a simple `SELECT COUNT(Column) FROM Table;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, your code is subject to SQL injection attacks -- as the comments on the question have explained.

But your issue is the scoping rules around your table variable.  You can fix that by using:

```
set @query = concat('select ', @colName, ' from ', @tableName, ' where ', @colName,' is not null');

insert into @tempTable (smth)
    exec(@query);
```

I don't think there is any way around the SQL injection vulnerabilities for the logic you have suggested.  However, your code is so non-sensical that I doubt that it is really representative of your actual code.

Comment: This still leaves a ***huge*** injection issue and, as it stands should *not* be used. I would hate to imagine what would happen if someone did `EXEC getLenCol N'1; CREATE LOGIN NewLogin WITH PASSWORD = '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;/*', N'*/ ALTER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER NewLogin;--';`

Comment: @Larnu . . . So comment on the *question*.  It is an issue with the OP's original code and there is no way to do what the OP is asking *without* an injection issue.

Comment: [I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63936171/how-to-fix-that-procedure-in-sql/63936404?noredirect=1#comment113059252_63936171). *"also the above is wide open to injection attack.s"*. And just because you are injecting doesn't mean you should create insecure code. INjection is still in 6th position for security vulnerabilities and, with respect, someone  like yourself should know the dangers of it. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql) This answer is **dangerous**, it's as simple as that, and should *not* be used.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I'd better hide.  I've used it in production systems.  It should be used carefully, but that doesn't mean it is **never** appropriate.

Comment: Injecting in production is fine, Gordon, it's explicitly that you haven't sanitised them, you know that.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems that many are not aware of the dangers of SQL Injection, including Gordon, I wanted to expand on that first. Let's, take the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63936404/2029983) (at time of writing), which gives the following:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC getLenCol
      @tableName  varchar(255),
      @colName varchar(255)
as
    DECLARE @query varchar(255)
    DECLARE @tempTable Table(smth varchar(255))
    set @query = concat('select ', @colName, ' from ', @tableName, ' where ', @colName,' is not null');

    insert into @tempTable  (smth)
    exec(@query);
GO
```

Now, let's be someone malicious:

```sql
EXEC dbo.getLenCol @colName = N'1; CREATE LOGIN NewLogin WITH PASSWORD = ''1'', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;/*',
                   @tableName =N'*/ ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER NewLogin;--';
```

So, what does the above, in the dynamic SQL run? Let's find out by adding `PRINT @query;` to the SP's definition:

```sql
select 1; CREATE LOGIN NewLogin WITH PASSWORD = '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;/* from */ ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER NewLogin;-- where 1; CREATE LOGIN NewLogin WITH PASSWORD = '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;/* is not null
```

And, with a little formatting for ease of reading:

```
select 1;
CREATE LOGIN NewLogin WITH PASSWORD = '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
/* from */
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER NewLogin;
-- where 1; CREATE LOGIN NewLogin WITH PASSWORD = '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;/* is not null
```

OH. OHHHHHHHHHHH. Congratulations you are the new proud owner of a SQL Server that has a new `sysadmin` `LOGIN`!

**NEVER**, inject unsanitised string into a string in SQL. **NEVER**.

Rather than repeating myself, I'm going to link to my article [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql), however, you can easily make the above query secure with a few of uses of `QUOTENAME`:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC getLenCol
      @schemaName sysname = N'dbo', --You should define the schema too
      @tableName  sysname, --An object can't be longer than 128 characters, so sysname is best
      @colName sysname
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @tempTable Table(smth varchar(255));
    SET @QUERY = CONCAT(N'SELECT ', QUOTENAME(@colName),N' FROM ', QUOTENAME(@schemaName), N'.', QUOTENAME(@tableName), N' WHERE ', QUOTENAME(@colName), N' IS NOT NULL;');
    PRINT @query;
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (smth)
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query;
END;
GO
```

And what happens if we run the above `EXEC` statement before? Well you get the statement below (with added formatting):

```sql
SELECT [1; CREATE LOGIN NewLogin WITH PASSWORD = '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;/*]
FROM [dbo].[*/ ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER NewLogin;--]
WHERE [1; CREATE LOGIN NewLogin WITH PASSWORD = '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;/*] IS NOT NULL;
```

And no surprised, that generated the error

> Invalid object name 'dbo.*/ ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER NewLogin;--'.

Now your dynamic statement is safe from injection.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend against this approach, firstly calling this procedure is as much, if not more typing that just doing a count. Compare the two

```
EXECUTE dbo.getLenCol @tableName = 'dbo.SomeTable', @colName = 'ID';
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM dbo.SomeTable;
```

Even with the shortened exec, and not using named parameters it is longer:

```
EXEC dbo.getLenCol dbo.SomeTable', 'ID';
```

It is very, very rare that a catch all query like this, with object names being passed as parameters is going to be the correct approach. There are some maintenance queries where it is useful, but these are the exception, not the rule.

If you must do this though, you should do a little bit of validation first, and check that both the table name and column name are valid before executing any dynamic SQL by using `COL_LENGTH(@tableName, @ColName)`. e.g

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC getLenCol @tableName SYSNAME, @colName SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN

    IF COL_LENGTH(@tableName, @ColName) IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(', @colName, ') FROM ', @tableName, ';');
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
        RETURN;
    END

    -- TABLE OR COLUMN WAS NOT VALID RETURN -1 TO INDICATE THAT
    SELECT -1;

END
```